# When polymorphic relation shouldn't be used?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Is it okay to use a `polymorphic relation` when there are lets say 6 common columns and 2 columns with different names?

I need to track car `maintenance` and `refueling`.

```
maintenances - table
    -date
    -km_driven
    -info (refers to maintenance info )

refuelings - table
    -date
    -km_driven
    -amount (refers to amount in liters)
```

So, should i use polymorphic relationship or not? Is it ok if there are more different columns per model?

Comment: What do you want polymorphic, the Maintenace model?

Comment: Problem is that i don't know if it's good to put those two tables above into one polymorphic table because both have only one different column

Comment: Wait, I think there is a misunderstanding, in laravel is not the table that is polymorphic but the relation, read here please: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 0):

IMHO for your case I will go for **single table inheritance** (STI), but you need a library like this [tightenco/parental](https://github.com/tightenco/parental) or this one [Nanigans/single-table-inheritance](https://github.com/Nanigans/single-table-inheritance).

Laravel codebase has no support for `STI` without an external library. You can try to use polymorphic relation to solve your case but you will end up with 3 different tables. I think you want to use a single table with two or even three models so my advice is to try one of the STI library above.

`STI` is appropriate when your models have **shared data/state**. *Shared behavior* is optional because can be defined per **Model**. An example could be different type of vehicle Models: *Car, Truck, Bike etc.*.

With **Polymorphic Relations** instead, a model can `belong_to` several models with a single association. This is useful when several models do not have a relationship or share data with each other, but have a relationship with the polymorphic class. An example could be the **Comment** Model that can belongs to other Models: *User, Post, Image* etc..